# Restcomm FireFox, No Answer/Rejected! Your call to +1234 was not answered

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, sip, restcomm

I've got chrome and Firefox on my Ubuntu Linux. I am trying to call +1234 (http://XXX.XX.X.X:8080/olympus/)but all I get is No Answer/Rejected! Your call to +1234 was not answered. On chrome I cant also make calls because connection is insecure. How can i fix this problem?

Comment: can you share some more details about how you've deployed restcomm?

Also some logs would be helpful